# How to get kubernetes components metric data in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, grafana, kubernetes-health-check, heapster

I am trying to get metric data like network in and out bytes, disk read and write speed, etc. On kubernetes dashboard, I am only getting memory and CPU data. I have even installed heapster, influx db and grafana in the kube-system namespace. When I run the command kubectl cluster-info it says, "This site can’t be reached." So, it seems the dashboard is running but not other API's. Is there any other way to fetch this metric data?

Comment: I would suggest you check out cAdvisor. It provides resource usage and performance characteristics of running containers in K8s cluster.

Comment: Grammatical corrections

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed heapster, influxdb and grafana. Therefore, you can aceess CPU, MEMORY and Storage Resouces by using the following command.

`kubectl top pods --all-namespaces`.

this command allows you to access resources consumption for pods.

furthermore, if you want to access resources consumptions for nodes.Then, you can shoot this command

```
kubectl top nodes
```

Comment: The above commands seemed to work but only giving me memory and cpu data not network or disk information.Is there anything which i could do to get these metrics value?.

Comment: The command "kubectl top pods -all-namespaces" should have another dash before all to be "kubectl top pods --all-namespaces"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get those data from heapster api.

Just add a new entry to your heapster.yaml file.
Under spec(service) add

```
type: NodePort
```

(actullly you are exposing the heapster API by doing so).

Now your heapster.yaml file portion should look something like this

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8082
  selector:
    k8s-app: heapster
```

Now deploy your heapster.yaml again.

Now get services list from your kubernetes cluster using the followng command.

`kubectl get services -n kube-system`

There you can see the port of heapster something like this:

```
80:31637/TCP
```

Now try to access the heapster API with the cluster IP and port.
Something like this:

```
http://192.168.99.100:31637/api/v1/model/metrics
```

You should be able to see the metrics now.
Refer https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/model.md for further information.